# C header to C# dll import, referenced float data type acting odd

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have the following C code (.h/header) and I need to translate it to c# however the result I'm getting is very random...  the LED color is not changing between calls but the flot values are and they seem entirely unrelated to the actual value (which I set).

Oddly enough, I set the value using the same struct and it works =S

```
typedef struct TSS_Color
{
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
}TSS_Color;

/**
* \brief Reads the color of the LED on the sensor.
*
* @param id The identifier for the 3-Space device.
* @param color The color of the device's LED is written to the referenced variable.
* @return An error code indicating either success or failure to execute the call. The code will also indicate the reason for the failure.
*/
EXPORT TSS_Error getLEDColor(TSS_ID id, TSS_Color *color);

/**
* \brief Sets the color of the LED on the sensor to the given RGB color.
*
* @param id The identifier for the 3-Space device.
* @param color The color the device's LED is being set to.
* @return An error code indicating either success or failure to execute the call. The code will also indicate the reason for the failure.
*/
EXPORT TSS_Error setLEDColor(TSS_ID id, TSS_Color color);
```

Then in C# I converted it to the following code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Color
{
    public float R;
    public float G;
    public float B;
}

    [DllImport("ThreeSpace_API.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "setLEDColor")]
    public static extern ResultEnum SetLedColor( 
        uint deviceId, 
        Color color
        );


    [DllImport("ThreeSpace_API.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "getLEDColor")]
    public static extern ResultEnum GetLedColor(
        uint deviceId, 
        ref Color color
        );
```

My problem is that the GetLedColor (which allegedly works fine in C) the color struct's floats all seem randomly made up, and their values shift and change regardless (they shouldn't).

Including code that makes use of the above code as well:

```
public void SetLedColour(Color color)
{
    var resultCode = ThreeSpaceInterop.SetLedColor(_deviceId, color);
}
public Color GetLedColour()
{
    Color result =new Color();
    var resultCode = ThreeSpaceInterop.GetLedColor(_deviceId, ref result);
    return result;
}
```

resultCode is showing "NoError" which is expected.

It should be noted that using OUT instead of REF does not fix the issue...

```
[DllImport("ThreeSpace_API.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "getLEDColor")]
    public static extern ResultEnum GetLedColor(
        uint deviceId, 
        out Color color
        );
```

Edit:
They provided a test cpp example, and the program works as expected, using the same library.

Here is their code in cpp:

```
printf("==================================================\n");
printf("Getting the LED color of the device.\n");
TSS_Color color;
tss_error= getLEDColor(device, &color);
if(!tss_error){
    printf("Color: %f, %f, %f\n", color.r, color.g, color.b);
}
else{
    printf("TSS_Error: %s\n", TSS_Error_String[tss_error]);
}
printf("==================================================\n");
```

Comment: Please show the real code. You have two functions called SetLedColor.

Comment: Updated code, sorry had a typo on the DllImport second method which was supposed to be GetLedColor which is using out Color color

Comment: What value does `GetLedColor` return to you? Does the status indicate success or failure? Although you declare it `out`, is it really `out`? In other words, is the function guaranteed to set all the fields? Should it really be `ref`?

Comment: Also, on the get, I have tried both out and ref keywords, doesn't change the resulting behavior.

Comment: How is TSS_ID  defined in C?

Comment: When you change to `ref`, are the values changed during the call, or do they remain at the values you set before you call?

Comment: BTW, I made the C# code fit without the horz scroll bar, and removed the spurious charset specification. Charset irrelevant since there is no character data here at all. But you wiped out my edit. That's a shame.

Comment: @ReedCopsey typedef unsigned int TSS_ID;

Comment: I guess I have to ask again. What does the function return to you? You seem to be ignoring the return value.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan they are changing to random, not staying at unassigned zero when the get is called (regardless of out/ref)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan returns a uint code, which is the expected NO_ERROR constant

Comment: The only thing that we cannot check is the calling convention. How do you know it is cdecl?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan 
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

located around the export functions is:
#ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C"
 {
#endif
Does that help?

Comment: No calling convention specified in C++ code. So, prob>0.9999 it is cdecl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the things that can go wrong:

- The calling conventions do not match.
- The function names do not match.
- The struct declaration is incorrect.
- The parameters do not match.
- You are calling the function incorrectly.
- The function is returning an error code.

Assuming what you have told us is correct, none of these potential problems apply. I am confident that your interop code is correct.

Therefore, the only remaining conclusions are that:

1. The C code is incorrect.
2. Your expectations of the C code are not correct.

The next step I would take would be to write some native code, using C or C++, and compare the behaviour of that code with your C#. I'd expect the behaviour to be the same. At which point you need to look into what could be up with the library code.

Comment: their example usable works fine unfortunately =/  I'll add their usage code to my question as well...

Comment: !! The problem seems to be related to a previous call to the sensor... Perhaps their driver is broken.  I commented out all other sections and the code worked, and then slowly introduced each other section.  I'll need to figure out why it's failing =/  Perhaps it's just internal..